# Error when routing to static - Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

So i'm trying to achieve file access restrictions.
For example, when getting "flowers.jpg" the URL looks something like this: .../static/uploads/zfds98ys/flowers.jpg

Routes file:

```
GET /static/uploads/*hashCode/*fileName     controllers.Application.staticAccess(hashCode: String, fileName: String)
```

Passed function:

```
def staticAccess(hashCode: String, fileName: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    if (true /*insert hash check here...*/ ) Redirect(routes.Assets.at("/public/uploads", fileName))
    else Redirect(routes.Application.notFound())
}
```

Im getting this error:

```
  Execution exception
  [MatchError: (/public/uploads,flowers.jpg) (of class scala.Tuple2)]

  123 // @LINE:12
  124 def at(path:String, file:String): Call = {
  125    (path: @unchecked, file: @unchecked) match {
  126 // @LINE:12
  127 case (path, file) if path == "/public/javascripts" =>
  128   implicit val _rrc = new ReverseRouteContext(Map(("path", "/public/javascripts")))
  129   Call("GET", _prefix + { _defaultPrefix } + "static/javascripts/" +  implicitly[PathBindable[String]].unbind("file", file))Execution exception
```

Why this is happening... ? 
The image exists in the given path. The code that i replaced worked fine (below):

```
GET /static/uploads/*fileName    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/uploads", fileName)
```

Comment: Did you remove the normal `Assets` route from your `routes` file?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is about        `Redirect(routes.Assets.at("/public/uploads", fileName))` not being sufficient (a route needs to be declared instead). I decided to go with another approach for now

Comment: Right. You can't redirect using reverse routes when the route doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This approach can't work by removing the original `Assets` routes, because in doing that you cannot `Redirect` to routes that don't exist. But if you have the original `Assets` routes there, then someone can just bypass it. You can make this work by invoking the `Assets` controller directly, instead of a redirect.

Route:

```
GET     /static/uploads/:hashCode/*fileName     controllers.Application.staticAccess(hashCode: String, fileName: String)
```

Controller function:

```
def staticAccess(hashCode: String, fileName: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    if (true /*insert hash check here...*/ ) {
        controllers.Assets.at("/public/uploads", fileName)(request)
    }
    else Future.successful(NotFound)
}
```

Comment: Of course, removing the `Assets` routes still hurts the rest of the application.